# Verify by calculation that a root lies between 2 and 3 (which equation do I put this in to, and what am I looking for?)

Tags: calculus, functions, numerical-methods

I am given
$$ y = 4cos(\frac{1}{2}x)$$
$$y = \frac{1}{4-x}$$
$$0 <= x < 4$$
When x = a, the tangents to the curves are perpendicular (see image for reference):
[image]

I have successfully done the first step and obtained:
$$ a = 4 - \sqrt{2sin(\frac{1}{2}x)}$$
I also have the derivative functions of each of the above functions.

Now I am to **verify by calculation that a lies between 2 and 3**.

I am not sure which equation to put my 2 and 3 in to find a sign change (that's what we have to do, right?). Also, I tried putting it in each of the equations (both of the curve equations and the derivative equations), but I couldn't find a sign-change anywhere. Where am I going wrong, and why?

**EDIT:** Let me add the answer key, since this question seems to be a tad confusing (and I'm confused too, so can't clarify):
[image]

Comment: How can $a$ depend on a $x$ ?

Comment: So the when x = a, the two curves have tangents that are perpendicular to each other -- the slopes of the curves at x = a are negative reciprocals. The question had me write out the $a = 4- \sqrt{2sin(.5x)}$ by using that fact. I'm past that part. Now I'm trying to figure out how to verify that this x = a lies between 2 and 3. (Is that what you meant to clarify?)

Comment: Why did you bring the condition to fixed-point form? Was that required in the task? I find that without the square root the terms $(4-a)^2$ and $2\sin\frac a2$ are easier to compare. The second term takes its maximum value $2$ at $a=\pi$ where the first term has a value smaller than $1$, and at $a=2$ the first term has the value $4$ which the second term can never reach.

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann, yes, the question asked me to get it into that form. I see, that’s an intuitive way to think about it.

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand the question correctly, I assume that the solution of:

$x = 4-\sqrt{2sin(\frac{1}{2}x)}$

is your a value.

So you want

$4-\sqrt{2sin(\frac{1}{2}x)} -x = 0$

Look at the function

$f(x) = 4-\sqrt{2sin(\frac{1}{2}x)} -x$

It is a continuous function from $2 \le x \le 3$

$f(2) = 0.7027$

$f(3) = -0.4124$

By the intermediate value theorem $f(x)$ takes on every value in the interval $[-0.4124,0.7027]$ at some x in $[2,3]$. So it hits 0 at some x in this interval.

Comment: Maybe one should also note that there is only one solution: $f$ is strictly decreasing in $[0,\pi]$ and negative in $(\pi, \infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=4 \cos \left(\frac{x}{2}\right);\;g(x)=\frac{1}{4-x}$$

Derivatives are
$$f'(x)=-2 \sin \left(\frac{x}{2}\right);\;g'(x)=\frac{1}{(4-x)^2}$$
Tangents are perpendicular at $x\in[0,4]$ means that the product of their slope is $-1$.

$$f'(x)g'(x)=-1\to 2 \sin \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-(4-x)^2=0$$
Let $h(x)=2 \sin \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-(4-x)^2$

We have $h(2)\approx -2.3;\;h(3)\approx 0.99$ therefore in the interval $(2,3)$ there is at least one root.

This root is about $x=2.61$.

There is another root, actually, at $x=5.07$, out of the given interval.

The points where the tangent are perpendicular are actually two

[image]

Comment: Okay. So you put $x=2$ and $x=3$ into $h(x)$. Can you tell me how you knew which equation to use to test the x values for a sign change? Could I have done this into the equations of the curves and gotten the same thing? This is my confusion. Can you tell me why not?

Comment: @Mathematician Your equation $p(x)=x-4+\sqrt{\sin \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}=0$ has the same solution than mine in the interval $[2,3]$. You have $p(2)= -0.702$ and $p(3)=0.412$. The solution is the same as the one I have found. It doesn't give the second point where the tangents are perpendicular. I edited my answer to add a graph